# SQL - Is there a way to force nulls in a DB?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a DB that does not allow null values in a certain table. But I need to work some validation from the code side for rows that may or may not have certain data.

Question: Is there a way to force nulls in SQL? For example if I had 13 columns in a table (none of which allow for null values) and I only wanted to INSERT data into one of them while leaving the others empty. Can this be done?

Comment: No- if a column does not allow NULL values then you can't put in a null value.  You can define a DEFAULT value for the column and only insert into some of them but you can;t have NULL as a default if the column does not allow nulls.

Comment: The answer is no. But there are some hacky workarounds. Like storing the string "NULL" or other sentinel values that your application will recognize as NULL, but I wouldn't recommend that approach (get messy real quick). If the schema does not allow NULLs there should be a good reason. If not, then allow NULLS

Comment: Cannot you use empty strings for texts, 0 for numbers and false for booleans?

Comment: Ok great I got it working. I was able to pass in empty strings. Thanks for the help all of you.

Comment: You might find http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3579079/how-can-you-represent-inheritance-in-a-database helpful.